# React native android debug.apk is not installing in One plus Nord

Tags: android, react-native

When I am running **react-native run-android** to run android app in debug mode in my **Oneplus nord**, I am encountered with following error.

Unable to install /android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF

Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF

Hence, Cannot install app in One plus physical device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using these commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
npx react-native run-android --no-jetifier
```

Comment: Cool! After digging lot into this. This worked for me.